# Reset Knox password

Tags: samsung-knox

I had installed Samsung Knox on my Galaxy Note 3 and now I have forgotten its password. It is not very clear what should I do, in order to reset the password.

From the [login page](https://my.samsungknox.com/en-US/#/login), when I click on the "Forgot password", it asks for an email. As I enter the mail, it says the email has not been registered.

How to reset the Knox password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you go to the web portal, follow the steps below:

- On the My KNOX User Portal, Click on Devices and select your device.
- Click on Reset KNOX Password.
- Launch your My KNOX if you aren't inside it already.
- Enter your new unlock code; tap Continue.
- Enter your unlock code again; tap Confirm.

From [To manage My KNOX](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/products/my-knox/how-to/manage-my-knox)