# Trouble accessing Samsung Knox & resetting the password

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, samsung-knox

I seem to have locked myself out of Samsung Knox (on a Galaxy Tab S2 - I've used [samsung-galaxy-tab](/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-tab) because there doesn't appear to be a tag for the S2 tablet yet).

I hadn't used my tablet for awhile. I turned it on and updated to the latest version of Android.

I had a notification asking me to load the Google Play store to update that as well, and after clicking this notification, at this point, the device locked with the Samsung MyKnox login screen.

I did originally set up Knox but haven't really used it since.

I tried both my device password and my Knox password, but these both came back as incorrect.

I'm able to log in to Knox online with my Knox password, so I followed the instructions [in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/142444/160779) (which are the same as the ones Samsung offers), but it's unclear what I'm meant to do: after clicking on 'Rest KNOX Password' on the web and confirming that action, nothing happens - either on the web or on my device.

On my device, I can pull down the notifications, but pressing the Home button does nothing - it seems to want me to get past this Knox screen.

I'm inexperienced with Knox and a bit inexperienced with the Android ecosystem in general. Have I locked myself out? What steps do I need to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I seem to have resolved this!

I restarted the device while it was on the Knox lock screen, and it booted up normally.

Going back in to Knox asked me to *set* a password (this may or may not have been because of the steps I followed on the website as described in the question above).

Either way, it appears that either *updating Android* or getting stuck logging in to Knox through the *Google Play Store notification* was the cause of the issue.

Restarting the device again and attempting to access Knox now lets me in.

(I'll leave this here in case anyone else comes across the same issue!)